# Symfony, @Method annotation not recognizing DELETE?

Tags: symfony, methods, annotations

Trying to delete an entity without a form button but instead a link but am getting an error that method wasn't set to DELETE when I made it in the annotations.

Error:

```
No route found for "GET /edit/delete/GREEN": Method Not Allowed (Allow: DELETE)
```

My delete function:

```
  /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $dano
 * @Route("/delete/{dano}", name="edit_deleteda")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteDAAction($dano) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('CIRBundle:SumitomoMain')->findOneByDano($dano);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find entity to delete');
    }

    $em->remove($dano);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('CIRBundle:Edit:delete.html.twig', array(
      'entity' => $entity
    ));

}
```

Twig template:

```
 ....codes...
                <td><a href="{{ path('edit_editeda', { 'dano': dano.dano }) }}" class="action">Edit</a> <a href="{{ path('edit_deleteda', { 'dano' : dano.dano }) }}" class="action">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Do you mean to set the header method to DELETE? (e.g. header methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, HEAD)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing apples and oranges.

Yes, that `@Method` deflation is correct, BUT, it is supposed to be used with HTTP protocol and **custom crafted requests** - those that can define **http method**.

- Forms can produce GET/POST method request
- Links can produce GET method request **only**

You can read more about HTTP's methods **[here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)**